# Deleted Compute Engine default service account

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I cannot create a virtual machines in GCE.. While creating it is showing the error message, i have attached my screen-shot of error message.. i will briefly explain what i have done..

--> I have deleted my compute engine default service account from my service account list.. later i created new service account..

--> While creating virtual machines i selected newly created service account, vm creating was failed but the error shows the deleted service account id is not found under service account..

--> While creating vm's it is referring my deleted service account id..

Now what i need to do? Is there is any solution to reactivate my Compute Engine default service account..
Completely iam struck now i cannot create new vms and kubernetes.
[image]

Comment: Could you show us in detail how are you creating the VMs?

Comment: Iam creating the vm via GCE console using default service account. As i deleted the default service account, i used another service account to create the vm and its working fine.. But in case of GKE, by default while creating a GKE cluster it will use the default service account, so it fails.

Answer (score 8):

You can now "undelete" service accounts by doing a curl request as below:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H "Content-length: 0" "https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID:undelete"
```

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID is the id of the account you want to recover

You can get a list of service accounts by running:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=service_account" --freshness=10y
```

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting_a_service_account

Comment: As of now, a command `gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete` is also available, which is easier to use (but calls the same API, in the end).

Answer (score 6):

To restore your google compute default service account, run the following gcloud command within your project:

```
gcloud services enable compute
```

---

In previous versions the command was known to be:

```
gcloud service-management enable compute.googleapis.com
```

As stated in this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69612457

Comment: FYI, I needed to user `services` instead of `service-management`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two default service accounts and I am not sure which one you are referring to:

1. Google API service account, in your case it is called: `933144605699@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`. It is a special service account. It is always created but never listed in gcloud or the web console. It is intended to be used by some of the internal Google processes on user's behalf. GKE may be one of the services that uses this account (I am not sure). 
   It is impossible to delete this account, the only thing you could do is to remove it from any roles on the project. By default it is an `Editor`. You can add it back any time.
2. Default service account: `933144605699-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`. This is a normal service account, which you may delete.

In the error message you pasted there is a different service account name, is it the new one you created? If this is the case, you might only need to go to IAM settings on the web console and add your user to service account actor. Take a look at this manual page: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#the_serviceaccountactor_role

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to find the removed SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID. Using Logging advanced queries is:

```
resource.type = "service_account"
protoPayload.authorizationInfo.permission = "iam.serviceAccounts.delete"
```

[Example here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrlvx.jpg)

**==> unique_id value is SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID**

2. Use the API provided by @sherief-el-feky :

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $ (gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H "Content-length: 0" https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID : undelete "
```

- Logging advanced queries: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2022, use

```
gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete <ACCOUNT ID>
```

`ACCOUNT ID` is the 21 digit `unique id (uid)` which last part of the deleted service account.

For example,

```
deleted:serviceAccount:abc-project@kubeflow-ml.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=123451234512345123451
```

`uid` is the last part of the above service account.